# Add bounty value as a comment in timeline

Tags: feature-request, bounties, timeline

Currently, there is no information about bounties worth values in timeline, [e.g.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/369294/timeline):

> [image: timeline]

It would be nice to add a value of bounty as comment part in timeline, i.e.

- bounty worth N reputation