# Add a custom message of a bounty as a comment part to the post timeline

Tags: feature-request, bounties, timeline, bounty-remarks

A bounty can have a custom message specified on the bounty start

> [image: Custom message box]

And placed as a notice when the bounty is in the active phase:

> [image: Active bounty]

That message will not be visible anywhere after the end of a bounty period.

Could we please add such a message in the timeline as a comment part? For instance:

> [image: Custom notice]

The bounty started comment part suggested to be used for a bounty worth value: [Add bounty value as a comment in timeline](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/385774/339911)

Comment: A related feature requests: [Add bounty remarks to a question's revision history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/110003). (That one is about the edit history rather than about the timeline.) Some of the [questions linked there](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/110003) seem related, too. You can also have a look at some other posts tagged ([tag:bounty-remarks]).